# React script stop working after changing API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a script which calls API from React and then triggers email notification function.

I was changing one part of it to call whole array of parameters instead of calling one parameter after another.

Here is part before change(working one). Console log shows correct response and I receive email notification as well.

```
const getApiData = () => {
const apiCall = (symbol) => {
  return `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=${symbol}&tsyms=USD&api_key=API-KEY-HERE`
}

const MAX_CHARACKTERS = 300

let bucketArray = ['']

for (let i=0; i < assets.length - 1; i += 1) {
  const symbol = `${bucketArray[bucketArray.length - 1]},${assets[i]}`
  if (i === 0) {
    bucketArray[0] = assets[i]
    continue
  }
  if (symbol.length < MAX_CHARACKTERS) {
    bucketArray[bucketArray.length - 1] = symbol
  } else {
    bucketArray[bucketArray.length] = assets[i]
  }
}

const getData = () => {
  Promise.all(
    bucketArray.map(req => {
      return axios(apiCall(req))
        .then(({ data }) => data)
    })
  ).then((data) => setDataApi(data))
}
getData()
};
```

Here is problematic one.

```
const getApiData = () => {
    const getString = symbol =>
      `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=${symbol}&tsyms=USD&api_key=API-KEY-HERE`;

    function getAxious(id) {
      const url = getString(id);
      return axios.get(url);
    }

    const BUCKET_SIZE = 150;
    const bucketArray = assets.reduce(
      (arr, rec) => {
        if (arr[arr.length - 1].length < BUCKET_SIZE) {
          arr[arr.length - 1] = [...arr[arr.length - 1], rec];
          return arr;
        }
        return [...arr, [rec]];
      },
      [[]]
    );

    bucketArray
      .reduce((acc, rec) => {
        return acc.then(results => {
          return Promise.all(
            rec.map(item =>
              getAxious(item).then(({ data }) => {
                return {
                  Symbol: item,
                  Open: data
                };        
              })
            )
          ).then(x => {
            return [...x, ...results];
          });
        });
      }, 
      Promise.resolve([]))
      .then(res => {
        setDataApi(res);
      });
  };
```

Here in console I receive empty array - `[]` no errors showed, but email notification also stops from working.

I'm changing the code since I need to call whole array from API in one call. Before I was calling one `symbol` after another.

What I did wrong that console doesn't show the correct response?

**EDIT1**

Here is bucketArray value

```
const assets = ['ADA','KAVA','DOGE'];
```

Comment: Can you add value of bucketArray in the question ?

Comment: @simbathesailor If I understand your question right, I just added an EDIT1 at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to understand completely, but  I think you want to collect all the results together and set it to the data using setDataApi.

Check the below code and let me know if it helps:

```
 async function getApiData() {
  const getString = (arr) =>
    `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=${arr.join(
      ","
    )}&tsyms=USD&api_key=API_KEY`;

  function getAxious(arr) {
    const url = getString(arr);
    return axios.get(url);
  }

  const BUCKET_SIZE = 150;
  const bucketArray = assets.reduce(
    (arr, rec) => {
      if (arr[arr.length - 1].length < BUCKET_SIZE) {
        arr[arr.length - 1] = [...arr[arr.length - 1], rec];
        return arr;
      }
      return [...arr, [rec]];
    },
    [[]]
  );

  const res = await getAxious(bucketArray);

  console.log("res", res);
  return res;
  // after this you can set  setDataApi(res);
}

// keep this useEffect sepearate

const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  async function getApiDatahandler() {
    const res = await getApiData();
    console.log(res);
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      getApiDatahandler();
    }, 1000 * 60);
    setTimer(timerId);
    setDataApi(res)
    // set the data setDataApi(res);
  }
  getApiDatahandler();

  return () => {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  };
}, []);

// useEffect(() => {
//     const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
//       getApiData();

//     }, 1000 * 60);

// }, [])
```

Comment: Can I open a chat with you for few minutes?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220484/room-for-hexycode-and-simbathesailor

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this codepen for a possible solution.
https://codepen.io/bcaure/pen/RwapqZW?editors=1011

In short, I don't know how to fix your code because it's quite a [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

```
// Mock API and data
const bucketArray = [[{item: 'item1'}], [{item: 'item2'}], [{item: 'item3'}]];
const getAxious = item => { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve({data: 'API data'}));
}

// Return promise that combines API data + input item
const recToPromise = rec => rec.map(item => { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => getAxious(item)
     .then(data => resolve({item, data}))); 
});

// Flatten array
const recPromisesFlatten = bucketArray.flatMap(recToPromise);

Promise.all(recPromisesFlatten)
  .then(res => { 
    const flattenRes = res.flatMap(({item, data}) => ({ Symbol: item, Open: data }));
    console.log(JSON.Stringify(flattenRes))
  });
```

What I'm suggesting to debug errors:

1. build your promise array first
2. then run Promise.all
3. then combine your data

Bonus: you can see flatMap instead of reduce for better readability.